# Unable to install an old version of the gem "rmagick"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I happen to have a bit old rails project, it's rails 3.2 and ruby 2.2.4. Because of this, installing some gems fails, in particular it's "rmagick -v '2.13.2'".

```
    $ gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/user123/.rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160826-3014-1j0i394.rb extconf.rb
    checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
    checking for gcc... yes
    checking for Magick-config... yes
    checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
    checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... no

    Can't install RMagick 2.13.2.
    RMagick does not work when ImageMagick is configured for High Dynamic Range Images.
    Don't use the --enable-hdri option when configuring ImageMagick.

    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
    need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
            --without-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include
            --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib
            --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=/home/user123/.rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

    extconf failed, exit code 1

    Gem files will remain installed in /home/user123/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
    Results logged to /home/user123/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out
```

I've tried unistalling the library "ImageMagick" and installing one with no hdri, but even that failed because there're other libraries which depend on "ImageMagick" with hdri, thus I haven't been able to reinstall it. 
And in general, reinstalling a library only for a single rails project doesn't sound a right thing to do.

What would you recommend me then? 
I'm on Arch Linux and have 2 rubies installed:

```
$ chruby
 * ruby-2.2.4
   ruby-2.3.1
```

Maybe I should upgrade it to a slitely newer version? Note that I don't want to break other dependencies in the project.

Comment: @fedorqui, re-read my question.

Comment: @fedorqui, it's already known what the error is.

Comment: @fedorqui, besides, the  error in my case is different.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the non-HDRI library at an alternative location and make sure its Magick-config is found first by doing something like this:

```
PATH="/alternative-path-you-choose/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16:$PATH" gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'
```

Comment: should I install it from sources only?